# How to specify a unit with Quickstatements in Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to add the type of unit for a property (centimeters) like width [1]
using Quickstatements [2].

In the UI it is pretty easy and visible like:
[image: Display of units in wikidata UI]

Adding a statement with additional qualifier[3] seems not to work, as I don't know the correct Wikidata property.

- [1] https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2049
- [2] https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:QuickStatements
- [3] https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:QuickStatements#Add_statement_with_qualifiers

I tried to use: type of unit for this property [P2876] like:

```
Q123384875|P2049|93|P2876|Q4407906
```

but that results into a warning like:
[image: resulting warning]

[image: Warning one]

[image: other issues]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

1. go to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:QuickStatements
2. Ctrl+F
3. search for "unit"
4. read the first entry for your search ;-)

[image: Screenshot]

In your specific case, you can use:

```
Q123384875|P2049|93U174728
```

Note that the centimeter (as unit of length) is [Q174728](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q174728), not [Q4407906](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4407906).

The data type that you want to specify is a [quantity](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Data_type#quantity). Instead, the syntax

```
Q123384875|P2049|93|P2876|Q4407906
```

is used for adding a qualifier to the statement (see [Help:QuickStatements §
Add statement with qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:QuickStatements#Add_statement_with_qualifiers)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not recognised the correct usage of units within the value string. Great spot!